# Получение Json из файлов и папок

Tags: php, json, файлы

В папке music на хостинге лежал папки типа

```
Папка № 1
Папка № 2
...
Папка № N
```

В каждой папке свои аудио

```
Аудио № 1
Аудио № 2
...
Аудио № N
```

Как-то можно получить JSON файл из этих папок и файлов в виде

```
{
  "music": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "Папка": "Папка № 1",
      "Аудио": "Аудио № 1",
      "url": "mysite.ru/music/Папка № 1/Аудио № 1.mp3"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "Папка": "Папка № 1",
      "Аудио": "Аудио № 2",
      "url": "mysite.ru/music/Папка № 1/Аудио № 2.mp3"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "Папка": "Папка № 1",
      "Аудио": "Аудио № 3",
      "url": "mysite.ru/music/Папка № 1/Аудио № 3.mp3"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "Папка": "Папка № 2",
      "Аудио": "Аудио № 1",
      "url": "mysite.ru/music/Папка № 2/Аудио № 1.mp3"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "Папка": "Папка № 2",
      "Аудио": "Аудио № 2",
      "url": "mysite.ru/music/Папка № 2/Аудио № 2.mp3"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "Папка": "Папка № 2",
      "Аудио": "Аудио № 3",
      "url": "mysite.ru/music/Папка № 2/Аудио № 3.mp3"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "Папка": "Папка № 3",
      "Аудио": "Аудио № 1",
      "url": "mysite.ru/music/Папка № 3/Аудио № 1.mp3"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "Папка": "Папка № 3",
      "Аудио": "Аудио № 2",
      "url": "mysite.ru/music/Папка № 3/Аудио № 2.mp3"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "Папка": "Папка № 3",
      "Аудио": "Аудио № 3",
      "url": "mysite.ru/music/Папка № 3/Аудио № 3.mp3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Результат

```
"2014": {
  "id": 2014,
  "folder": "music/Певец_1",
  "audio": "..",
  "url": "https://site.ru/music/Певец_1/.."
},
"2015": {
  "id": 2015,
  "folder": "music/Певец_1",
  "audio": ".",
  "url": "https://site.ru/music/Певец_1/."
},
"2016": {
  "id": 2016,
  "folder": "music/Певец_1",
  "audio": ".",
  "url": "https://site.ru/music/Певец_1/Музыка № 1.mp3"
}
```

Comment: Это вопрос не JSON, а вопрос кролинга (crawl).

Comment: А есть пример как это реализовано? Или может быть ссылки на какие-то статьи, где что-то подобное реализовано.

Comment: ls или find  в помощь (для *nix). Возможно du нужен. Преобразование формата - второе дело.

Comment: А php файл нельзя создать, который в данной папке "music" будет искать файлы и папки и в итоге формировать готовый json? Думал что такое возможно сделать

Comment: в теории можно, но это не проблема json. Нужно теги корректировать для объективности.

Comment: если вы имели ввиду теги в вопросе, то я уже скорректировал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот примерно так можете сделать.
А подробно о методах что есть здесь в коде можете прочитать [тут](http://php.net/).

```
$mp3_arr = array();
//$somePath ваща родительская директория
$somePath = 'Song';
$dirs = glob($somePath . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
var_dump($dirs);
$id = 1;
foreach($dirs as $dir){

    $results_array = array();

    if (is_dir($dir))
    {
        if ($handle = opendir($dir))
        {
            while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== FALSE)
            {
                if ($file!="."&&$file!=".."){
                    $mp3_arr['music'][$id]["Папка"] = $dir;
                    $mp3_arr['music'][$id]["Аудио"] = $file;
                    $mp3_arr['music'][$id]["url"] = "mysite.ru/music/".$dir."/".$file;

                    $id++;
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($mp3_arr);
$mp3_json = json_encode($mp3_arr);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь используется `readdir`. 
И он первые две записи возвращает `.` и `..`

```
1. `.`  - это запись каталога для текущего каталога
2. `..` - является каталогом для текущего каталога на один уровень выше в иерархии
```

Или вот второй вариант с использованием [glob](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php) для поиска песен в папках.

```
$mp3_arr = array();
//$somePath ваша родительская директория
$somePath = 'Song';
$dirs = glob($somePath . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
var_dump($dirs);
$id = 1;
foreach($dirs as $dir){

    $results_array = array();

    if (is_dir($dir))
    {
        if ($handle = opendir($dir))
        {
            foreach(glob($dir.'/*.mp3') as $file){
                $mp3_arr['music'][$id]["Папка"] = $dir;
                $mp3_arr['music'][$id]["Аудио"] = $file;
                $mp3_arr['music'][$id]["url"] = "mysite.ru/music/".$dir."/".$file;

                $id++;
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($mp3_arr);
$mp3_json = json_encode($mp3_arr);
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял то в ответ в json получил последний файл в последней папке. И больше никаких данных

Comment: @Kolhoznik id пропустил

Comment: Работает, только еще такой вопрос. Вот есть в папке music/Певец_1/Музыка № 1.mp3 есть один файл, то в json попадает три значения. В вопросе вставил что получаю

Comment: для каждой папки получаю по два лишних записи https://site.ru/music/Певец_1/. и https://site.ru/music/Певец_1/..

Comment: @Kolhoznik изменил код, посмотрите.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало как нужно. А можете пояснить почему выводились записи с "." и ".."?

Comment: @Kolhoznik Посмотрите ответ, пояснил там в чем дело.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое.